# separating values of a single column in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am having a field named categoryid in a question table which can have multiple values inputted into it for showing different categories.
now i want to separate each value and get it individually.

the values are separated by , character

for example

```
categoryid varchar
3
3,8
5,9,7
8,5,7,3,2
```

How can i separate each of them using sql queries?
please help

Comment: categoryid a varchar or nvarchar type?

Comment: perhaps you should look at normalizing your data? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @T table
(
  category_id varchar(10)
)

insert into @T
select '3' union all
select '3,8' union all
select '5,9,7' union all
select '8,5,7,3,2'

;with C(ID, category_id) as
(
  select cast(left(category_id, charindex(',', category_id+',', 1)-1) as int),
         stuff(category_id, 1, charindex(',', category_id+',', 1), '')
  from @T
  union all
  select cast(left(category_id, charindex(',', category_id+',', 1)-1) as int),
         stuff(category_id, 1, charindex(',', category_id+',', 1), '')
  from C
  where len(category_id) > 0
)
select ID
from C
```

Comment: It is splitting the data but after joining all of then.........I want it in a way in which a query can split anyone of the above datas

Comment: @Abhishek Ok. Which one do you want to split? Should be solved by adding a where clause to the first part of the CTE. `where SomeColumn = 'SomeValue'`

Comment: i am able to split 2 or i am able to split 3 but not both types.i mean if i write a query to split 2 it doesnot work for splitting more than those values and viceversa

Comment: @Abhishek - The query I have provided for you is recursive and it will split up to 100 values without modification. If you have more than that you should add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the end of the query.